# Language bar not showing on github repository

Tags: javascript

Github repository is not showing the language of project. Repo Link :- https://github.com/shubhamextraxyz/Contract_Deployment_Infura_Web3.js

The file is a simple repo with 100% Javascript, but why it's not showing?

Any help appreciated!